# Windows won't Restart, can't access Task Manager or launch certain Programs

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, avg-antivirus

I recently encountered the problem that Windows 10 hangs on restarting and shutdown. I have to turn off the machine my the power button. I also can't launch Windows task manager. I've tried a safe mode boot and startup repair but that hangs. I recently tried to run AVG PC tuneup's check disk but had to cancel it half way through. Whenever I try and access the hard disk through file explorer I get a message saying that Microsoft Windows is not responding. If I click end task it shows a black screen with a cursor and nothing else. This might be down to me writing a windows application in C++ as I specified the window destroy option return to be 1 instead of a safe exit with 0. So I'm worried that Windows has a memory leak or something. What can I do to get my computer working again?

Comment: No return code can "destroy Windows". Seems like a problem with Windows or a virus infection. Try: (1) `chkdsk`, (2) [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), (3) [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) to add in your post the SMART data of the disk.

Comment: Cheers Harry, managed to boot to safe mode. I was getting "not enough resources to run Microsoft Windows" at command prompt before safe mode. Sfc /scannow would not run in Windows proper because I couldn't open cmd with administrative rights. Sfc /scannow is running in safe mode, just hope there's enough memory to complete. I'm going to run chkdisk afterwards since I was trying to run AVG's version of that. I doubt this is a virus. I think I messed about when programming with things I didn't understand.

Comment: I don't think a user-mode program can destroy Windows in this way. If you are almost out of disk space, free some. Windows needs a few gigabytes to be free. If nothing is found, the only solution would be to do [Repair Install](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: Okay sfc /scannow didn't return any problems.

Comment: I have 32gb free of about 500gb

Comment: Chkdisk /f is now running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was some operating system settings that were modified
by the AVG anti-virus.

My recommendations is not to use AVG. I have also had it once destroy half
of my Startup menu, so I don't trust it any more.

Windows Defender has enormously improved and is now a quite good anti-virus,
so you don't need a third-party product. And Windows Defender will never destroy
the Windows setup.

Comment: I accidentally put some programs back to sleep and now I can't run AVG tuneup. What an awful piece of software. AVG should be ashamed.

Comment: Also had user profile log on service not available briefly. Terrifying. Everything appears to be fixed. Thanks you Harry and Moishe for your helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Windows C++ application runs at startup (if it does, remove it), a clean (not hybrid) restart should eliminate that issue. If necessary, try the following:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter the following two lines to shut down completely:

> powercfg -h off
>
> shutdown /s /t 0

However, has Windows 10 updated? A number of [issues have been found with the April update](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsofts-april-2019-updates-are-causing-windows-to-freeze/), as well as recent others.

There are a number of solutions for the multiple issues, such as booting into Safe mode and removing the update (though MS will try to reinstall 'em), or uninstalling the non-MS anti-malware suite (unsafe).

Comment: The C++ program is just an application it doesn't run at startup. After I've checked the C drive for errors, I'll do this if it won't restart or turn off. I think the main problem is Windows just crashing when doing basic things now and running out of memory.

Comment: I also think my version of Windows 10has updated recently... Maybe it's just a recent bug.

Comment: 32 GB may not be enough... empty Recycle and delete some unneeded files to give more room.

Comment: Chkdsk appears to be running, half way done.

Comment: Okay, I've performed those commands as you suggested. My laptop appears to be hanging on shutting down.

Comment: Okay so I woke up some programs that AVG tuneup put to sleep and now task manager suddenly works. Don't think there was any disk damage. My laptop now restarts and shuts down. I think it put some critical Microsoft stuff to sleep and wouldn't let me shut down.

Comment: @SamuelAlbanMeachem, now update the AV, e.g. AVG suite, to comply with Windows changes. See https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/14/microsoft-confirms-two-known-issues-for-recent-windows-10-updates/